# Magento 2: How to create event in magento2

Tags: magento2

I need to create an event in my custom module of magneto2.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-create-events.html

app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Controller/Index/Test.php

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Controller\Index;

class Test extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{

    public function execute()
    {
        $textDisplay = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(array('text' => 'Mageplaza'));
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch('mageplaza_helloworld_display_text', ['mp_text' => $textDisplay]);
        echo $textDisplay->getText();
        exit;
    }
}
```

app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/etc/frontend/events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="mageplaza_helloworld_display_text">
        <observer name="mp_display_text" instance="Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Observer\ChangeDisplayText" />
    </event>
</config>
```

app/code/Mageplaza/HelloWorld/Observer/ChangeDisplayText.php

```
<?php

namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Observer;

class ChangeDisplayText implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $displayText = $observer->getData('mp_text');
        echo $displayText->getText() . " - Event </br>";
        $displayText->setText('Execute event successfully.');

        return $this;
    }
}
```